# cv::MatIterator equivalent in numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

What is the equivalent of a cv::MatIterator for an RGB image in numpy?
I read about `numpy.nditer` but I'm not able to formulate my requirement exactly using it.

For example consider the below C++ code using OpenCV iterating over each pixel and assigning an RGB value:

```
cv::Mat rgbImage(someheight, somewidth, CV_8UC3);
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> first = rgbImage.begin<cv::Vec3b>()
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> last = rgbImage.end<cv::Vec3b>()

while (first!=last){
    *first = (get <cv::Vec3b> value from somewhere)
    ++first;
}
```

In the above code, the MatIterator `first` is used to assign (R,G,B) values of type cv::Vec3b directly at each pixel in the image.

Considering the below Python code,

```
rgbImage = np.zeros((someheight, somewidth, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
first= np.nditer(rgbImage)
while not first.finished():
     ???
```

can someone provide an example of what an equivalent numpy version might be like to directly assign a tuple of (R,G,B) values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to iterate over an array is by using [`np.ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) and one for loop, then you can modify your image inside of it, here is an example of how to use it:

```
import numpy as np

# generate a random numpy array as loaded from cv2.imread()
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(8, 10, 3))

for (x,y,z), value in np.ndenumerate(img):
    do_something(img[x,y,z]) # modify to do whatever you want
```

Remember that OpenCV uses BGR instead of RGB. So if you would like to assign magenta color (BGR=(255,0,255)) to the pixel (x=1, y=2) in a black image of dimensions 3x4 you will do the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> img = np.zeros((3, 4, 3), dtype = np.uint8)

>>> for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(img[:,:,0]):
>>>     if x == 1 and y == 2:
>>>         img[x,y,:] = (255,0,255)    
>>> print img
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [255   0 255]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```

Comment: `for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(img[:,:,0]):
    img[x,y,:] = np.array([255,0,255])`. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted a way to iterate in the 2D (x,y) coordinates, and assign the rgb color values. Thanks for it.. accepted!